How do I insert or ignore a row and return its id in a single query with go and sqlite?
I'm trying to insert a new row into a sqlite table and return its id, or return the id of the existing row, but I can't get both cases to work. I'm using golang with mattn/sqlite3. From what I've read the way to do this would be something like this:
var userid int64
row := s.db.QueryRow(`
    INSERT OR IGNORE INTO users (email) VALUES (?);
    SELECT id FROM users WHERE email = ?;`,
    email, email)
err := row.Scan(&userid)

But this fails with a "no rows" error in the case where the row did not exist, and does not insert the row, as if the first statement is being simply ignored. If I compress it into one statement with a returning clause like this:
var userid int64
row := s.db.QueryRow(`
    INSERT OR IGNORE INTO users (email) VALUES (?)
    RETURNING id;`,
    email)
err := row.Scan(&userid)

Then it fails in the case where the row already exists, because the "ignore" also skips the returning clause.
I don't understand why the first version fails. Is golang's sql interface not capable of executing multi-statement queries with return values? I can't find any documentation on this. Or am I doing something else wrong?

Can you add RETURNING id from the first query? If it needs to be a single query, you could put the logic into a CTE and finish with RETURNING.

You can use UPSERT statement.
create table users (id int primary key,email varchar(100) unique );

First insert
insert into users values
 (3,'test3@mail.com')
on conflict(email) do update set email=excluded.email
returning id

Returns



id




3



Next insert
insert into users values
 (3,'test3@mail.com')
on conflict(email) do update set email=excluded.email
returning id




id




3



If you have other column, suppose updated_at
insert into users values
 (3,'test3@mail.com')
on conflict(email) do update set updated_at=current_timestamp
returning id

